# missed logic in finding sum using recurssion ,got segfault

Tags: c, recursion

I tried to achieve following using recurssion but im getting segfault pls correct me??

i tried solving problem using permutation of set {1,,3,5,7} but failed to output the required result
    print all compositions of a number in odd parts, i.e. for n = 8:
    7 + 1
    5 + 3
    5 + 1 + 1 + 1
    3 + 3 + 1 + 1
    3 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
    1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1

sumto8(a,start,sum1) is://choosing element of concern 
sumto8(a,start,sum)is ://choosing element of concern

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

int sumto8(int*,int,int);
int n=4;
int c=8;

int main()
{
    int a[]={1,3,5,7};
    sumto8(a,0,c);
}

int sumto8(int* a,int start,int sum)
{
   if((sum<0) || (start>(n-1)))
   return -1;

   if(sum==0)
   {
       cout<<" "<<a[start];
       return printf("+ %d",a[start]);
   }
   if(i==-1)
      {
       return-1;
      }
      if(j==-1)
      { 
        return -1
      }




   else
   {
      int sum1=sum-a[start];


      int i=sumto8(a,start,sum1);



      int j=sumto8(a,start+1,sum);
   }

   return printf("+ %d",a[start]);
}
```

it seems the if condition for sum<0 is not checking properly...

```
output :segfault
```

Comment: Please fix your code snippet so that there aren't dozens of empty lines that make it difficult to read.

Comment: Also, asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you say

> it seems the if condition for sum<0 is not checking properly...

i found out that your checking like this

```
   if((sum<0) && (start>(n-1)))
   return -1;
```

how if the "and" you change it to "or"

```
   if((sum<0) || (start>(n-1)))
   return -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found one problem with the nested for loop within main. It should read `for(int j=0; j<c; j++)`. You have it as `j<c+1` which will go outside the bounds of the array as you have declared it

edit: there is another problem with this section:

```
    /*dp[start][sum1]=*/sumto8(a,start,sum1);//choosing element of concern 
    start++;
    /*dp[start][sum]*/=sumto8(a,start,sum);
```

In the second call to `sumto8` you haven't commented out the `=`. You have a lot of blank space and commented code. You also never call the `isVisited()` function the way everything is commented right now and at the end of the `sumto8` function you have two identical return statements at the end. It would really help if both yourself and everyone here if you cleaned it up a bit.